# Getting items from ViewBag in data (function) vue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, model-view-controller

Good day.

How i can get elements from the viewbag in data?

```
   ViewBag.Headers = headers;
   return View();
```

```
data: {
   title: 'Select headers for processing',
   list1: @ViewBag.Headers, <= need to get here
   list2: ['1','2','3']
},
```

and use list1 here

```
   <div class="col-md-5">
      <select size="10" class="form-control" id="list1" multiple>
         <option v-for="item1 in list1">{{item1}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not mix razor and vue at the same page. You may have hard time keeping things right. Both do the same end of the day. But If you are in SPA then vue will be more flexible.

You can do it without vue.

```
    <select asp-for="selectedHeader" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Headers" class="select">  
        <option value="">Choose Header</option>  
    </select>
```